# Is it possible to convert headers and body of HTTP POST req to JSON and repeat to the upstream

Tags: http, nginx, lua

I want to repeat some HTTP requests inside of Nginx to 3rd party service to analyze them after. Is it possible to convert HTTP POST request (headers and body) to JSON document without LUA scripting and send it somewhere via HTTP?

Comment: It's totally possible but secretly forwarding POST requests from inside a webserver to a third party sounds well shady, so I'm not going to tell you how to do it.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect